# Creating a draggable, resizable div container with inner scrollbars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a container, made up of an outer div with a scrolling inner div, like so: (note this is stripped down version of what I'm actually doing)

HTML:

```
<div class="faq-clone">
    <div class="faq-clone-content">
        Some text goes here.
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.faq-clone {
    overflow: auto;
}

.faq-clone-content {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 375px; 
    max-height: 400px;
}
```

The idea is to have `.faq-clone` draggable and resizable, but for resulting scrollbars to still only appear on the inner div, `faq-clone-content`. I'm working with an existing project, so I started just by added `.draggable()` in jQuery, as shown in the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jessikwa/5LrL3/2/

Simple enough, it still functions as it should. To get the resizing I understand the CSS will need to change. I added `.resizable()` to `.faq-clone` and tweaked the CSS so that the outer container has the width/height set and overflow set to hidden, as seen in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jessikwa/5LrL3/4/

The container resizes fine, but the inner scrollbars are lost. Changing `overflow:hidden` on `.faq-clone` doesn't seem to be the answer, but without it I gain scrollbars on the outer div, which is undesirable. Any ideas on how the CSS should be set to accomplish this?

Comment: Looks like the issue is use of .resizable.  This guy adds a div and sets overflow explicitly: http://jsfiddle.net/Ka7P2/2/.
They have it working.  In your case perhaps add an inner element on which you can set `overflow: auto`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery to set `faq-clone-content` to the size of it's parent `faq-clone` seemed to do the trick.

```
$(".faq-clone-content").css('height', faqClone.height() + 'px');
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jessikwa/5LrL3/9/